# PostgREST: disable direct access to everything but functions

Tags: postgrest

I wonder if it's possible to deny access to all tables/views and only allow to functions? I just want to control the data I pass.

I can't disable access with pg roles for the tables, cause the functions use the same tables.

I can put on NGINX before PostgREST and disable anything that doesn't start with `/rpc`, but that the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and expose a dedicated schema(using the [db-schema](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/configuration.html#db-schema) config) that only contains functions. This way no table will have direct access through the REST API.

The above follows the [schema isolation](https://postgrest.org/en/stable/schema_structure.html#schema-isolation) guide on the postgrest docs.